# ndk-build eclipse argument: not find class

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk, installation

We are developing a system for Android devices. For that we are using FC16, Eclipse, SDK, NDK.

In Eclipse: Run > External tool > External Tolls Configurations > we have the tabs:

```
[Main]
Location:
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/javah
Working Directory:
${workspace_loc:/MyProject/bin}
Arguments:
-d ${workspace_loc:/MyProject/jni} com.myproject.MyActivity

[Refresh]
Specify Resources
MyProject - JNI
```

Then when clicking on "Apply" and "Run" it comes the error message:

```
Error: Could not find class file for 'com.myproject.MyActivity'.
```

But, on the other hand if we go on terminal into the directory /MyProject and run the command:

```
ndk-build
```

No error appears, and the program runs as native C++ on Android.

What is missing on Eclipse IDE? Should be something to do with the [Argment] as informed in [External Tolls Configurations], or is it something else we missed?

All comments and suggestions are welcome and highly appreciated.

Comment: One of the comment is you cannot use JDK 7 with Android SDK (Android requires JDK 5 or 6). Maybe this can lead to the misbehavior.

Comment: Thanks! I have installed JDK 6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add -classpath it worked for me

```
-d ${workspace_loc:/MyProject/jni} -classpath ${workspace_loc:/MyProjec/src} com.myproject.MyActivity
```

Comment: is there a solution that would work for any kind of project , no matter what its name or package are , and no matter where the jdk location is ?

Answer (score 4):

There is one error yet. The correct is:

```
-d ${workspace_loc:/MyProject/jni} -classpath ${workspace_loc:/MyProject/src} com.myproject.MyActivity
```

The diference is the `t` in `MyProject/src`.

It worked on my project.