# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class name: ANDROID NDK javah

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, adt

Im learning to code Android in NDK on WINDOWS Eclipse.... been following a Tutorial Book by Sylvain Ratabouil. So im in  Run  |  External Tools |  External Tools Configurations… 
creating a new program configuration.

**Name:  MyProject javah**

**Location : ${env_var:JAVA_HOME}\bin\javah.exe**

**Working directory: ${workspace_loc:/MyProject/bin}**

The problem comes In arguments...
when i try
Arguments:  –d ${workspace_loc:/MyProject/jni} com.myproject.MyActivity
as it says in the book

i get when i click run

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class name: –d
```

when i try **${workspace_loc:/MyProject/jni} com.myproject.MyActivity}**

i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class name: C:\Paul\Workspace\MyProject\jni
```

UPDATE:
i put -classpath first and it's running but can not find the class file for com.myproject

Comment: Funny, this don't worked for me. I'm in mac.
This solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200373/ndk-build-eclipse-argument-not-find-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after further research....
i did it.

i set arguments to

**-d ${workspace_loc:/MyProject/jni} -classpath C:\Paul\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-17\android.jar;${workspace_loc:/MyProject/bin/classes} com.myproject.MainActivity**

Answer (score 1):

I also spend some long time on this problem when working with the the mentioned book about Android NDK.

Please note the following: 
The java classname is NOT written in `{ }`, just write something like `com.myproject.MyActivity`

The `-classpath` parameter can receive several paths devided by semicolon.

In my case this parameters worked:

**Location:**

```
${env_var:JAVA_HOME}\bin\javah.exe
```

**Working Directory:**

```
${workspace_loc:/myproject/bin}
```

**Arguments:**

```
-d ${workspace_loc:/myproject/jni} -classpath ${workspace_loc:/myproject/bin/classes};"C:\Eclipse\sdk\platforms\android-18\android.jar" com.myproject.MyActivity
```

(BTW.: The correct Adroid.jar file is referenced inside the Eclipse project.)

Answer (score 1):

Me also facing the same problem tonight, i found a less tedious way as following...

1. as "Location" set the javah from your system
2. as "Working directory" set the project's bin/classes directory (**${workspace_loc:/HelloWorld/bin/classes}**)
3. as "Argument" set the jni folder as the output directory and point out the class on which you want to run the javah (**-d "${workspace_loc:/HelloWorld/jni}" com.example.helloworld.MainActivity**)

NB :: Dont forget the double qoute (") around the output in the third step (**"${workspace_loc:/HelloWorld/jni}"**)

A full picture is also attached following

[image: All 3 steps in a single picture]

Answer (score 0):

well in case ...

1-> Goto ( cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin)

2-> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin>javah -jni -classpath 
F:\Android_OpenGLES\FibonacciNative\bin\classes 
-d F:\Android_OpenGLES\FibonacciNative\jni\ com.example.fibonaccinative.FibLib

without creating/using environment variable ...

Answer (score 0):

YES THAT'S CORRECT 
more abstract would be

```
-d ${workspace_loc:/MyProject/jni} -classpath ${env_var:ANDROID_SDK_HOME}\platforms\android-16\android.jar;${workspace_loc:/MyProject/bin/classes} com.myproject.MyActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

Following I tried successfully

```
javah com.sense.kios.Calculation
```

**Note: Include package name.**

In case if javah not found as an command and you getting

```
The program 'javah' can be found in the following packages:
 * gcj-4.6-jdk
 * gcj-4.7-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
 * openjdk-6-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

use direct path of jdk path, in my case it's `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/javah`.