# Cannot find src/main/jni from the Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-ndk

In order to use NDK in my application, I included an external tool at `Preferences -> Tools -> External Tools`.

Here's what I did.

[image]

As I right-clicked a class and chose the external `javah` command to create a c class, it didn't work and left a following message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class name: /src/main/jni
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:107)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:64)
    at com.sun.tools.javah.JavahTask.run(JavahTask.java:503)
    at com.sun.tools.javah.JavahTask.run(JavahTask.java:329)
    at com.sun.tools.javah.Main.main(Main.java:46)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I properly created the `jni` folder under the `main` directory, and I'm still not clear why I keep getting this message.

Here's my development environment.
OS: OS X El Capitan
Android Studio: 2.2.2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631116/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-not-a-valid-class-name-android-ndk-javah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by modifying the `Parameters` and `Working Directory` as follows.

- Parameters: `-classpath $Classpath$ -v -jni $FileClass$`
- Working Directory: `$ProjectFileDir$/app/src/main/jni`